# How to use Discord API to send a private message given a user ID (Discord.py) ( CLOSED )

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py, dm

I want to send a message in a dm but from a user account not a bot. I have searched the whole internet (including stackoverflow) but i can't seem to find anything. Is this kind of thing possibly using discord's api and if, then any resources would be greatly appreciated.

( Do not respond with: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message or https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#message-create i just wan't someone to script it for me. )

Comment: Yes it’s possible but self-bots are not allowed by Discord TOS.

Comment: Hi, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Usually, people won't really help you if you don't show that you put some effort in yourself already.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible. But self botting isnt allowed by the Discord TOS. But you can follow some tutorials online in youtube regarding that!

**Note: You may get warned/ Permanently banned by discord.**